# Way to read PHP "if" tree without skipping to the bottom?

Tags: php

I have been attempting to make a script that puts sprite IDs into categories, like this. 
http://rhcafe.us.to/categoryxml.php

However whenever it runs, it only places sprites that have been checked as a "Generator" and ignores the rest.

```
  $basexml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><views></views>';
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($basexml);

  $enemiesovcat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $enemiesovcat->addAttribute('name', 'Enemies - Overworld');

  $enemiesdescat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $enemiesdescat->addAttribute('name', 'Enemies - Desert');

  $enemiesundercat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $enemiesundercat->addAttribute('name', 'Enemies - Underground');

  $enemiestowercat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $enemiestowercat->addAttribute('name', 'Enemies - Tower/Castle');

  $enemiesshipcat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $enemiesshipcat->addAttribute('name', 'Enemies - Airship');

  $enemiesundercat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $enemiesundercat->addAttribute('name', 'Enemies - Underwater / Beach');

  $enemieslavacat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $enemieslavacat->addAttribute('name', 'Enemies - Lava');

  $enemiessnowcat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $enemiessnowcat->addAttribute('name', 'Enemies - Snow');

  $enemiesjuncat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $enemiesjuncat->addAttribute('name', 'Enemies - Jungle');

  $enemiesghostcat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $enemiesghostcat->addAttribute('name', 'Enemies - Ghost House');

  $enemiessky = $xml->addChild('category');
  $enemiessky->addAttribute('name', 'Enemies - Athletic');

  $enemiesbigcat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $enemiesbigcat->addAttribute('name', 'Enemies - Big');

  $platformscat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $platformscat->addAttribute('name', 'Platforms');

  $bossescat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $bossescat->addAttribute('name', 'Bosses / Boss Objects');

  $mechscat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $mechscat->addAttribute('name', 'Level Mechanics');

  $gencat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $gencat->addAttribute('name', 'Spawners and Generators');

  $controllerscat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $controllerscat->addAttribute('name', 'Controllers');

  $rotcontrolledcat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $rotcontrolledcat->addAttribute('name', 'Rotation Controlled');

  $linescat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $linescat->addAttribute('name', 'Controlled - Uses Lines');

  $pathscat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $pathscat->addAttribute('name', 'Controlled - Uses Paths');

  $itemscat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $itemscat->addAttribute('name', 'Items and Blocks');

  $effectscat = $xml->addChild('category');
  $effectscat->addAttribute('name', 'Lighting and Effects');

  $ccategory = $xml->addChild('category');
  $ccategory->addAttribute('name', 'Uncategorized Sprites');

  $bcategory = $xml->addChild('category');
  $bcategory->addAttribute('name', 'Unused/Beta Sprites');
```

These are the XML categories that are the  entry. These work just fine.

```
  $fields = array();
  $getfields = mysql_query('select * from fields');
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($getfields)) {
    $s = $row[1];
    if (!isset($fields[$s])) $fields[$s] = array();
    $fields[$s][] = $row;
  }

  $getsprites = mysql_query('select * from sprites order by id');
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($getsprites)) {
      if ($row[7] == 1)
        $cat = $enemiesovcat;
      if ($row[8] == 1) 
        $cat = $enemiesdescat;
       if ($row[9] == 1)
         $cat = $enemiesundercat;
       if ($row[10] == 1)
         $cat = $enemiestowercat;
       if ($row[11] == 1)
         $cat = $enemiesshipcat;
       if ($row[12] == 1)
             $cat = $enemieslavacat;
       if ($row[13] == 1)
             $cat = $enemiessnowcat;
       if ($row[14] == 1)
             $cat = $enemiesjunglecat;
       if ($row[15] == 1)
             $cat = $enemiesbigcat;
       if ($row[16] == 1)
             $cat = $controllerscat;
       if ($row[17] == 1)
             $cat = $eventscat;
       if ($row[18] == 1)
             $cat = $platformscat;
       if ($row[19] == 1)
             $cat = $bossescat;
       if ($row[20] == 1)
             $cat = $rotcontrolledcat;
       if ($row[21] == 1)
             $cat = $linescat;
       if ($row[22] == 1)
             $cat = $pathscat;
       if ($row[23] == 1)
             $cat = $itemscat;
       if ($row[24] == 1)
             $cat = $effectscat;
       if ($row[25] == 1)
             $cat = $enemiesghostcat;
       if ($row[26] == 1)
             $cat = $enemiessky;
       if ($row[28] == 1)
             $cat = $mechscat;
       if ($row[29] == 1)
             $cat = $enemiesundercat;
       if ($row[30] == 1)
             $cat = $gencat;
       else
           $cat = $ccategory;
    $sprite = $cat->addChild('attach');
    $sprite->addAttribute('sprite', strval($row[0]));

}
```

Here's where the trouble comes. This part takes each row (which is a checkbox inputted from another script, if it's checked it returns 1, and assigns it to the category that it's checked 1 in.) However, only the "Generators" category gets counted, and the "Generators" category so happens to be the last "if" statement on that tree.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Change your second through last `if` to an `elseif`. Each and every `if` is running separately. When you get to the bottom, if `$row[30]` != 1, the else will run, overwriting whatever any previous if set.

Comment: Or, remove the else portion and just set `$cat` to a default value like `$cat = $ccategory;` at the top. If any of the other `if` statements are true, they will overwrite that value.

Comment: One issue you have now (and will have when doing it like this) is that more than one `if` is true, you will only ever have a reference to the last one.

Comment: Changing that "if" to the "elseif" fixes the category above it, so I guess that works. The second solution fails completely.

Comment: Well, is there another way to do this? I think the current one sucks too.

Comment: By "at the top" I mean the top of the `if` chain. Right after `while` and before the first `if`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did. But it makes the XML fail.

Comment: It is noteable that keeping that "else" statement makes the script run fine (but with the issues, of course) but without it, the script fails.

Answer (score 0):

Your last `if ... else` determines the outcome of `$cat`. The effect of all previous `if` statements is overwritten by that last `if ... else`.

I would suggest the following code to initialise the array of categories as they correspond to the check boxes.

Note however that:

- in your code you had nothing for `$row[27] == 1`, and that there are duplicate strings (e.g. *$enemiesundercat* occurs twice);
- the file you referenced has an extra level of *view* nodes, each with their *category* children, but this *view* level is not generated by your code;
- the order of categories in the linked file is different. For example *Rotation Controlled* comes immediately after *Platforms* in the linked file
- There are some other differences, like *Unused/Crashing Sprites* is present in the file, but not in your code;
- I have assumed you want the lay-out exactly as in the referenced file;
- I have assumed the values of the check boxes are stored in the same order as the categories appear in the referenced file;
- In your code you load data from the *fields* table, but you never use it. So I skipped that part.

Code:

```
// Define the bare XML structure
$xml_str = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<views>
    <view name="Enemies">
        <category name="Overworld"/>
        <category name="Desert"/>
        <category name="Underground"/>
        <category name="Tower/Castle"/>
        <category name="Airship"/>
        <category name="Underwater / Beach"/>
        <category name="Lava"/>
        <category name="Snow"/>
        <category name="Jungle"/>
        <category name="Ghost House"/>
        <category name="Athletic"/>
        <category name="Big"/>
    </view>
    <view name="Platforms">
        <category name="Platforms"/>
        <category name="Rotation Controlled"/>
        <category name="Controlled - Uses Lines"/>
        <category name="Controlled - Uses Paths"/>
    </view>
    <view name="Mechanics">
        <category name="Bosses / Boss Objects"/>
        <category name="Level Mechanics"/>
        <category name="Spawners and Generators"/>
        <category name="Controllers"/>
    </view>
    <view name="Misc">
        <category name="Items and Blocks"/>
        <category name="Lighting and Effects"/>
    </view>
    <view name="Unused / Useless">
        <category name="Unused/Beta Sprites"/>
        <category name="Unused/Crashing Sprites"/>
    </view>
</views>';

// Build XML object from that string
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_str);

// Collect category nodes from XML into a flat array
$cat_nodes = [];
foreach ($xml->view as $view_node) {
    foreach ($view_node->category as $cat_node) {
        $cat_nodes[] = $cat_node;
    }
}

// Load data from the database (sprite value and checkbox values)
$getsprites = mysql_query('select * from sprites order by id');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($getsprites)) {
    // Checkbox flags start in column 7 (zero-based)
    // Find first occurrence of a "1" in those columns
    $index = array_search(1, array_slice($row, 7));
    if ($index !== false) {
        // Found a "1": Get corresponding category node, and add an "attach" node to it
        $sprite = $cat_nodes[$index]->addChild('attach'); 
        // Set the sprite attribute of that new node
        $sprite->addAttribute('sprite', strval($row[0]));
    }
}

// Echo the resulting XML content:
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($xml)->ownerDocument;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
echo htmlentities($dom->saveXML());
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work either. It doesn't display the output at all in this manner...

Comment: Updated my answer, as I could use the info in your question that you added since my first answer a few days ago. There are several issues you might need to get straightened out, see the points I raise in my answer. But the code works for me, and generates an XML like you referenced.